# Set an awk,sed output to a variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

**UPDATE:**
Now I have a simpler file to handle, similar to this:

```
127.0.0.1 25 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 25 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 32828 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 32830 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 32906 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 32908 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 32984 127.0.0.1
```

(first column ip_local, second column port_local and last column ip_foreign)

All I have to do is to send the awk output to a variable. 
The code I managed to write is this, but I still have problems to process the text file...

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `cat DEV0_IPsListSep.txt`;
do
ip_local=$(awk '{print $1}' $i);
port_local=$(awk '{print $2}' $i);
ip_foreign=$(awk '{print $3}' $i);
if [$port_local < 3200] ||  [$ip_foreign != 127.0.0.1] || [$ip_foreign != 
192.168.1.1]
then
echo $ip_foreign >> IPFinalList.txt;
fi
done
```

---

I have a bash script that processes a file with two columns. The first column is the local ip addresses, the other is the one of the foreign addresses.

Example:

```
127.0.0.1:25 127.0.0.1:33862
127.0.0.1:25 127.0.0.1:36498
127.0.0.1:25 127.0.0.1:37338
127.0.0.1:25 127.0.0.1:37410
127.0.0.1:25 127.0.0.1:38320
127.0.0.1:25 127.0.0.1:39428
127.0.0.1:25 127.0.0.1:39514
127.0.0.1:25 127.0.0.1:39768
127.0.0.1:25 127.0.0.1:39846
127.0.0.1:25 127.0.0.1:40376
```

I would like the script to assign the outputs of sed and awk commands to my custom variables, to separate IPs and ports.

I tried to create a script but still receive syntax errors...

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `IPslist.txt`;

ipLocal=$(awk '{print $1}' | sed -e 's/:.*//' $i)
portLocal=$(awk '{print $1}' | sed -e 's/.*://' $i)
ipForeign=$(awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/:.*//' $i)
portForeign=$(awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/.*://' $i)

if [ $portLocal < 3200 ] ||  [ $ipForeign != 127.0.0.1 ] || [ 
$ipForeign != 192.168.1.1 ]

then

echo $ipForeign >> IPFinalList.txt

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

With single **awk** process (optimized solution):

```
awk -F':|[[:space:]]+' '$2<3200 || $3!= 127.0.0.1 || $3!= 192.168.1.1' IPslist.txt > IPFinalList.txt
```

Comment: Hi Roman, I appreciate your help!
I don't know if this is the solution to my problem. The output of this awk command is identical to the source file; it would be interesting for me to print all the IPs (of the first column) that comply with the conditions of the if...

Comment: @Dandelion, it's obvious: your conditions `if [ $portLocal < 3200 ] ||  [ $ipForeign != 127.0.0.1 ] || [ 
$ipForeign != 192.168.1.1 ]` cover all your input lines, i.e. all your current input lines fit your conditions. Otherwise, you have make a mistake defining conditions

Comment: OK! I got it. But with your awk command, even with the " : " separator, I keep getting an incorrect output. I also tried to get a new file, separating everything first: example 127.0.0.1   25    127.0.0.1 (first column is the local address IP, second column is the local port and the third column is the foreign IP), but I still don't get the IPs list that I want, (all I see on the new file is the IPs list and ports like the original file).

Comment: @Dandelion :  rather than carry on an extended session of corrections in comments, please update your Q with your (new) best understanding of the problem and just say "please see updates in Q above". Good luck.